# Create / Modify CoreData Entity (fields / elements) on startup based on API fields

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data, dynamic

Is it possible to create a Coredata entity based from a json blob i received from an API?

Our app fields are very dynamic and can change from time to time. but I only need to fetch them on startup. I currently don't know a way to create an entity based on an array of fields.

Comment: No you can’t do that at runtime, you need to think of another solution

Comment: How much data?  Can you hold it in memory?  You could just persist the json to disk as a file

Comment: they are aiming for 1million data sets.

Comment: It is possible to build a model dynamically at runtime.  But you will be in a difficult position if you need to subsequently change the model - managing the versions/migrations will be a real headache.